# UWP Sqlite throws database is locked exception

Tags: sqlite, uwp, async-await, windows-10, windows-10-universal

When I execute the following code

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<CommentModel>> GetTypeWiseComment(int refId, int commentType)
        {
            try
            {
                var conn = _dbOperations.GetSyncConnection(DbConnectionType.UserDbConnetion);

                var sqlCommand = new SQLiteCommand(conn)
                {
                    CommandText = "bit complex sqlite query"
                };

                List<CommentModel> commentList = null;

                Task commentListTask =
                    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => commentList = sqlCommand.ExecuteQuery<CommentModel>().ToList());
                await commentListTask;
                var commentsList = new ObservableCollection<CommentModel>(commentList);

                return commentsList;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }
```

Sometimes I get the following exception

```
Message: database is locked
InnerException: N/A
StackTrace:    at SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare2(IntPtr db, String query)
   at SQLite.SQLiteCommand.Prepare()
   at SQLite.SQLiteCommand.<ExecuteDeferredQuery>d__12<com.IronOne.BoardPACWinAppBO.Meeting.MeetingModel>.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Diagnostics.Tracing.FieldMetadata>..ctor(Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Diagnostics.Tracing.FieldMetadata> collection)
   at BoardPACWinApp!<BaseAddress>+0xaa36ca
   at com.IronOne.BoardPACWinAppDAO.Comments.CommentsDAO.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<GetCommentTypeWiseComment>b__0()
   at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x38ec7b
   at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x4978cc
```

Can anyone point out what's wrong with my code?

There is another sync process going on the background and sometimes it has a bulk of records which may take more than 10 seconds to execute. If this above code happens to execute at the same time as the sync writes to the DB, it might block the reads, right?

If so how do I read from SQLite while another process writes to the DB?

Thank you.

Comment: [WAL](https://sqlite.org/wal.html) mode

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Could you elaborate it a bit more?. Thanks.

Comment: Did you read all of the information at the link?

Answer (score 0):

as @Mark Benningfield mentioned enabling WAL mode almost solved my problem. However, there was another issue that creates a lot of SQLite connections on my app so I solved that by creating a Singleton module which handles database connections.

Please comment and ask if you require more information if you encounter a similar issue. Thanks.